# Edit specific lines only in text document

Tags: regex, notepad++

I wish to edit lines in a text document that contain only a specific string.

So for example if I have

ABC-123-Bob
ABC-124-Bob
ABC-123-Bob

I need the end result to replace Bob with Mary since the line contains 124.

ABC-123-Bob
***ABC-124-Mary***
ABC-123-Bob

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `124-\K(\w+)`

Replace with: `Mary`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F0FAr4/1)

Answer (score 0):

In Find:

```
 ((?=.*?WORD1)[^\r\n]*)(WORDTOREPLACE)
```

In Replace:

```
 $1WORDTOREPLACEWITH
```